# How do you Stream an image into a database using Hibernate?

Tags: java, image, hibernate

Pretty simple question with almost no answers on the web.  I am using byte[] as my object.  Currently I am reading the entire image into memory and then writing it.  Very simple.

```
    @Column(name = "FILE_DATA")
private byte[] fileData;
```

I want to Stream it in.  So I guess I need to use inputStream, but hibernate does not like that.

How do I set this up?

EDIT:

I tried this but got a -314 db2 error:

```
Blob b = null;
        try {
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.com", 80));
            URL urls = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = urls.openConnection(proxy);
            b = new BlobImpl(conn.getInputStream(), conn.getContentLength());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        att.setFileData(b);
        this.theDao.save(att);
```

Comment: Ahhhh...all this time, I was assuming that the file was *local*.  This is a great question, but I think you need to flesh it out more.  Try including a simple bare-bones method.  Don't worry about catching exceptions.

Comment: As a test, can conn.getInputStream() be used to store the file on the local file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Blob data type for inserting and fetching the images from database. It wil also provide you the option of Binary input stream. Just Use your db field as blob and create a blob ojbect instead of byte array.

```
b.getBinaryStream()
```

Also you can create Blob from `bytes[]`

```
Hibernate.createBlob(bytes);
```

And the simplest solution Saving on the hard drive and keeping information about the image on database.

Comment: So how do I set up the column?

Comment: '@Column( name = "FILE_DATA" ) @Lob(type = LobType.BLOB)'

Comment: You are giving me just enough to make me want more.  Is there some actual code?  To create a blob, you need the content length.  how do I get that with a stream?  Do I have to read the stream first?  If so, this is not helping.

Comment: You don't have to read the stream. You can use `File.length()`.

Comment: I tried this and got a -317.  I believe this might work if DB2 was set up correctly.

Comment: Hibernate.createBlob(InputStream stream) is deprecated. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#createBlob(java.io.InputStream)

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is to keep filenames (URLs) in the databases and stream data from the disk (network resources) and stream them.

I would prefer this approach for web - when you just return an URL and it's handled by browser and Apache/Nginx (so you don't have to worry about streaming at all).

Comment: This is the answer that is all over the web, but for some of us, it has been decided to save it to a database.  This answer does not answer the question asked.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "hibernate does not like that"?

Here's how simple it can be to define.

```
@Entity Photo {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id = null;

    private String filename = null;

    @Lob
    private byte[] bytes = null;
    }
```

Then to load the data into the object...

```
String filename = // Where ever this comes from...
File file = new File(filename);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

Photo photo = new Photo();
photo.setFilename(filename);

// Create and fill the byte array from the file.
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
is.read(bytes);
photo.setBytes(bytes);
```

Then eventually tell Hibernate to save it in the database.

```
session.saveOrUpdate(photo);
```

Comment: This is not streaming.  This is reading into memory and then saving it.  I need to open the stream, and then send it to the database and save it.  I don't want the memory impact of loading lots of images...

Comment: Oh.  You want to stream it *directly* into the database, outside of Hibernate?  You're right, this isn't that at all.  However, java.sql.Blob (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) does have methods that might work for you.